# Can “list_display” in a Django ModelAdmin display other fields of realated table?

Tags: django, django-models

I can't get "list_display" to display field from related table.

models.py

```
class product(models.Model):
    product_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    EAN = models.CharField(unique=True, editable=False, max_length=13)
    Product_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class price(models.Model):
    price_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    EAN = models.ForeignKey(product, to_field="EAN", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Vendor = models.ForeignKey(vendor, to_field="Vendor_name", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Qty = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    Price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, null=True)

    panels = [
        FieldPanel('EAN'),
        FieldPanel('Vendor'),
        FieldPanel('Qty'),
        FieldPanel('Price'),
    ]
```

hooks.py

```
class price_admin(ModelAdmin):
    model = pricelist
    menu_label = 'price'
    menu_icon = 'pilcrow'
    menu_order = 300
    add_to_settings_menu = False
    exclude_from_explorer = False
    list_display = ('EAN_id', 'Vendor_id', 'Price') # <-Here I have a problem
    list_filter = ('Vendor_id__Name',)
    search_fields = ('Vendor_id__Name', 'EAN_id__EAN')
```

I'm able to get **"Vendor_id__Name"** to work in **"list_filter"** and **"search_fields"**, but when I put **"Vendor_id__Name"** to **list_display**, I get this error:

```
AttributeError: Unable to lookup 'EAN_id__Product_name' on price or price_admin
```

So, what is the right way to display field(Vendor_id__Name in my case) from related table?
Any help would be really appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ivan Starostin noticed you have a typo in related field name. Other option you can use - a method field or basically - a callable that [list display](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display) do accept:

```
class price_admin(ModelAdmin):
    ...
    list_display = ('vendor_name', # other fields)

    def vendor_name(self, obj):
        return obj.EAN.Product_name
    vendor_name.short_description = 'Vendor name'
```